Change the color of the footer to red
I am converting Excel to PDF using VBA macro code, and I want the center footer to be red, so i'm using below code.
ws.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&color#00FF00" & "HIGHLY SENSITIVE"

I have tried the code above to change the color using &color property,but it did not work.

The general format to change colour is &K and hex coded colour:
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .CenterFooter = "&KFFFF00" & "YELLOW"
    .RightFooter = "&KFF0000" & "RED"
    .LeftHeader = "&K00FF00" & "GREEN"
End With

